# Сумма двух DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Допустим у нас есть два датафрейма:

```
test =pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b'], data=[[1,2],[3,5],[5,7]])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
test2 =pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b'], data=[[1,2],[3,5]])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таким образом получается что у одного есть индекс которого нет у другого.

Теперь если мы сделаем сложение `test+test2` мы получим:

[image: Сложение двух DataFrame]

Есть ли возможность сделать так, чтобы в сумме датафреймов, в индексе которого не было в одном датафрейме, ставились значения датафрейма у которого был этот индекс, вместо NaN которые имеем сейчас??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [DataFrame.combine_first(other)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) после суммирования.

Пример:

Исходные DataFrame'ы:

```
In [18]: d1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b'], data=[[1,2],[3,5],[5,7]])

In [19]: d2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b'], data=[[1,2],[3,5],[8,9]], index=[0,1,4])

In [20]: d1
Out[20]:
   a  b
0  1  2
1  3  5
2  5  7

In [21]: d2
Out[21]:
   a  b
0  1  2
1  3  5
4  8  9
```

Решение:

```
In [22]: res = d1.add(d2).combine_first(d1).combine_first(d2)
```

Результат:

```
In [23]: res
Out[23]:
     a     b
0  2.0   4.0
1  6.0  10.0
2  5.0   7.0
4  8.0   9.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте через метод [add()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html):

```
sum = test.add(test2, fill_value=0)
```

- отсутствующие значения в другом датафрейме 
  будут заполнены значением **fill_value**